# Can't move files into aliases stored on the Finder's Favorites sidebar?

Tags: finder, alias

I'm trying to make some aliases and add them to my Finder favorites so that they can be renamed without altering the original folder in any way (the original folder is on a shared work network).

I'm able to create the alias, rename the alias folder to something I want, and add them to my Finder favorites. But I am unable to drag files into the alias from the favorites sidebar. When I try, I am not met with the typical blue highlight you'd expect to see when a file can be dropped into the folder, like in the second image.

I'm still able to move files into the alias folder as long as I drop them directly in the folder and not the finder shortcut.

Any idea if there's a solution? I've tried making symbolic links and it demonstrated the exact same behavior as regular aliases.

[image: Trying to move a file into an alias' Finder favorites shortcut. No blue highlight indicating that the file can be moved there]

[image: Moving a file into a regular folder's Finder favorites shortcut]